# Python: Error sending more than one email in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail

I have made a development who let me to send emails. If I try to send an email to one receipt there is no problem. But, If I try to send the same email to more than one receipts then I've got an error. I don't want to send an email to several receipts, what I want is to send one email to each of the receipts.

The error that I've got is:

```
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/reports/pregame.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.send_mail(subject, message, fileName)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/reports/report.py", line 48, in send_mail
    message = mail.create_message()
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/com/mail/mail.py", line 100, in create_message
    message.attach(MIMEText(self.params["message"], "plain"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/mime/text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

To send an email I have this class:

```
import base64
import logging
import os
import os.path
import pickle
from email import encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


class Mail:
    def __init__(self, params):
        '''
        :param params: It's a dictionary with these keys:
        from: Email account from the email is sended
        to: Email account who will receive the email
        subject: Subject of the email
        message: Message of the email.
        game: Next games
        '''
        self.params = params

    @staticmethod
    def get_service():
        """Gets an authorized Gmail API service instance.

        Returns:
            An authorized Gmail API service instance..
        """

        # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
        SCOPES = [
            #'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
        ]
        creds = None
        # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'com/mail/credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        return service

    @staticmethod
    def send_message(service, sender, message):
      """Send an email message.

      Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        sender: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        message: Message to be sent.

      Returns:
        Sent Message.
      """
      try:
        sent_message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=sender, body=message)
                   .execute())
        logging.info('Message Id: %s', sent_message['id'])
        return sent_message
      except errors.HttpError as error:
        logging.error('An HTTP error occurred: %s', error)

    def create_message(self):
        """Create a message for an email.

        Args:
        sender: Email address of the sender.
        to: Email address of the receiver.
        subject: The subject of the email message.
        message_text: The text of the email message.

        Returns:
        An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
        """
        #message = MIMEText(message_text)
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['from'] = self.params["from"]
        message['to'] = self.params["to"]
        message['subject'] = self.params["subject"]
        message.attach(MIMEText(self.params["message"], "plain"))
        routeFile = self.params["routeFile"] + self.params["fileName"]
        fileName = self.params["fileName"]
        # Open PDF file in binary mode
        with open(routeFile, "rb") as attachment:
            # Add file as application/octet-stream
            # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())

        # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
        part.add_header(
            "Content-Disposition",
            f"attachment; filename= {fileName}",
        )
        # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
        message.attach(part)
        s = message.as_string()
        b = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(s.encode('utf-8'))
        return {'raw': b.decode('utf-8')}
```

To send an email, I'll do it with this method:

```
def send_mail(self, subject, message, fileName):
    args = self.params["destiny"]
    if self.params["competition"] == COMPETITIONS.LF1 or self.params["competition"] == COMPETITIONS.LF2:
         data = SearchData(args, "subscriptors.emails=")
    else:
         data = SearchDataFIBA(args, "subscriptors.emails=")
    emails = data.get_result().getData()

    for item in emails:
         print(f"Enviamos informe a la cuenta: {item['email']}")
         params = {
             "from" : "basketmetrics@gmail.com",
             "to" : item["email"],
             "subject": subject,
             "message" : message,
             "fileName" : fileName,
             "routeFile" : f"output/reports/{self.params['destiny']}/"
        }
        mail = Mail(params)
        message = mail.create_message()
        service = mail.get_service()
        mail.send_message(service, "basketmetrics@gmail.com", message)
```

My application has secure access to google account.

I don't know how I cannot send more than an email in a row when I have no

problem to send only one e-mail.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit I:**

To reproduce the error, you can test it with this test code:

```
import unittest
import os
from com.mail.mail import Mail


class TestSendMail(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..')))
def test_send_mail(self):
    message = "¡¡¡Hola!!!\n\nOs enviamos el informe pre partido previo a vuestro próximo partido.\n\nSaludos,\n\nBasketmetrics.com"
    subject = "Informe pre partido"
    fileName = "name_of_the_file"
    emails = [{"email" : "receipt1@gmail.com"}, {"email" : "receipt2@gmail.com"}]

    for item in emails:
        print(f"Enviamos informe a la cuenta: {item['email']}")
        params = {
            "from" : "sender@gmail.com",
            "to" : item["email"],
            "subject": subject,
            "message" : message,
            "fileName" : fileName,
            "routeFile" : "route to the file"
        }
        mail = Mail(params)
        message = mail.create_message()
        service = mail.get_service()
        mail.send_message(service, "sender@gmail.com", message)
```

Also, you have to change some values for your own values and the file credentials.json file of your own google account

**Edit II:**

I have found where it produces the error but not why. The problem comes up when I invoque for second time the class Mail. In that moment I pass some parameters to the constructor with params variable. In that variable I pass the text of the message. This message is create outside of the loop.

If I read the first 120 characters of what receives the Mail class in params["message"] in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, params):
    '''
    :param params: It's a dictionary with these keys:
    from: Email account from the email is sended
    to: Email account who will receive the email
    subject: Subject of the email
    message: Message of the email.
    game: Next games
    '''
    self.params = params
    print(f"message received: {params['message'][:120]}")
```

For the first time, I've got the content of message variable:

```
message received: ¡¡¡Hola!!!

Os enviamos el informe pre partido previo a vuestro próximo partido.

Saludos,

Basketmetrics.com
```

But the second time, I should receive the same text!!! But I receive an error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/test/test_send_mail.py", line 26, in test_send_mail
    mail = Mail(params)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/reports/com/mail/mail.py", line 27, in __init__
    print(f"message received: {params['message'][:120]}")
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

If I read all the message without any limit or characers. For the first time, I receive the content of the variable message. But in the second time, I receive a very big string os characters, here is a little example:

```
lGWFBVZzhQc3pDNWdiNmhnMW1odDZHcmlFZWsyClZvTTBRT1R2dXpWaWlyZkpleS9mZXhtR3V3V2hTV0JjWERtSUNnWENTQVJ1QjdrN1Nzd3BrZ0c1Rkl3MXVDMmNyZk95ZUhySVM1dHQKSUh2T1YvWW1Pd2YzL3B2WEpLaEMza
```

Why I receive this string of charanters instead of the value of message variable?

I have check it that If I put message variable inside the for loop, instead of outside of the loop ... It works!!! I receive the two mails!!!

But, this solution isn't usefull because I want to reuse my code and I need to pass some values through variables.

So, why in the second time I don't receive the value of message variable and I receive a long string of characters?

How can I fix this error? Why it happens this error?

**Edit III:**

Checking the type of the value that I receive in the constructor of Mail, for the first time is "string":

```
typeof: <class 'str'>
```

But in the second time is "dict":

```
typeof: <class 'dict'>
```

And checking the keys of self.params["message"] are:

```
keys: dict_keys(['raw'])
```

I dont't understand anything ... How is it possible that params["message"] has the value of message variable and the second time params["message"] has modified its type to raw?

**Edit IV:**

I have modified the content of message variable from ...

message= ""

To ...

mesage = "¡¡¡Hola!!!0x0a0x0aOs enviamos el informe pre partido previo a vuestro próximo partido.0x0a0x0aSaludos,0x0a0x0aBasketmetrics.com"

But it doesn't work. I've got the same error.

**Edit V:**

I have modified the contento of message variable. Now, instead of plain text, I'm going to send an html ...

```
    message = """\
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>
                Hi, this is a test!!!
            </p>
            <p>
                Best regards!!!
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
```

To do send this message, you have to modify this instruction in method create_message of Mail class:

message.attach(MIMEText(self.params["message"], "plain"))

to this:

message.attach(MIMEText(self.params["message"], "html"))

And ... I've got the same error!!!

I don't know what to do anymore ...

**Edit VI:**

Last attempt ... I have modified the text of the message removing "strange" character like "" or "<" and I have send a simple text with the message "Hello".

So, my message variable now is:

```
message = "Hello"
```

And I have modified again the format of the email, from "html" to "plain"

And ... I've got the same error in my second email!!!

This is frustrating ... :((((((

Comment: Any chance reducing that to a [mre]? Somehow you've ended up with a dictionary instead of a string for one of your arguments. How did that happen? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
def send_mail(self, subject, message, fileName):
```

Where argument `message` is the message text to be sent. But we have in your function `test_send_mail':

```
def test_send_mail(self):
    message = "¡¡¡Hola!!!\n\nOs enviamos el informe pre partido previo a vuestro próximo partido.\n\nSaludos,\n\nBasketmetrics.com"
    # code omitted

    for item in emails:
        # code omitted
        message = mail.create_message() # overlaying message text with return value from create_message
        service = mail.get_service()
        mail.send_message(service, "sender@gmail.com", message)
```

In the `for item in emails:` loop, you have overlaid `message` with the return value from the call to `mail.create_message()`, so for the next iteration `message` is not a string anymore. This, I believe is your problem. You need to use a different variable name for either the return value from the call to `mail.create_message()` or for the message text.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution would be to have a small list of all the email ids, and run through the for loop and you can send the mails, Or you can actually use this package from python to help you assist you in your work,

A simple example would be like this

```
def send_mail(names, emails, senderMail, password, subject):
  port = 587
  password = password
  total = len(names)
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', port)
  server.starttls()
  server.login(senderMail, password)
  cc = 0
  for i in range(len(emails)): 
    body = '' #body of the mail, you can actually add html also please check the documentation

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = senderMail
    msg['To'] = emails[i]
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))


    text = msg.as_string()

    server.sendmail(senderMail,emails[i], text)

    cc += 1
    print(cc , " / ", total)

  server.quit()
```

If you want a easier approach attaching images you can check this package also,
[Please check this github repo for detailed work flow](https://github.com/saran-surya/certificate-gen)

Comment: Hi @SARAN SURYA!!!! Thanks for your help!!! I appreciated a lot, but I think that your solution is to send emails in no secure mode. And I'm trying to send emails in secure mode. I mean, you are sending emails allowing to use your google account by applications in not secure mode and I try to do the contrary, send emails without allowing to use my google account by applications not secure. Here you can find more info how I'm trying to send the emails: https://blog.mailtrap.io/send-emails-with-gmail-api/